# Angular 2 - how can a child component speak to a parent component?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Angular 2 - how can a child component speak to a parent component?

I used @input for parent to child which works fine.

What would I use to do child to parent?

**This is my compiler error I get:**

[image]

Comment: Can't believe Angular2 make this thing so complex. It's one of the most important features on a component-based approach, still it looks painfully counter-intuitive and cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@Output` to trigger events from the child component. The parent one can register processing on them.

Here is a sample

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  (...)
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output()
  someEvent: EventEmitter;

  constructor() {
    this.someEvent = new EventEmitter();
  }

  triggerEvent() {
    this.someEvent.emit('some value');
  }
}
```

and its use in the parent component:

```
<child (some-event)="printValue($event)"></child>
```

FYI `$event` contains the value `'some value'`.

You can notice that Angular2 supports two-way binding at this level:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  (...)
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input()
  value:string
  @Output()
  valueChanges: EventEmitter;

  constructor() {
    this.valueChanges = new EventEmitter();
  }

  triggerUpdated() {
    this.valueChanges.emit('some value');
  }
}
```

and its use in the parent component:

```
<child [(value)]="someVar"></child>
```

**Edit**

To call a method from the parent component, you need to inject it into the child one.

You need to be careful at this level to cyclic dependency in imports and that hoisting isn't supported for classes (use a class before it's created).

See this answer for more details:

- [How can i access the values from parent component in angular2 using dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153877/how-can-i-access-the-values-from-parent-component-in-angular2-using-dependency-i/35154016?noredirect=1#comment58027454_35154016).

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  (...)
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AppComponent)) parent:ParentComponent) {
    (...)
  }
}
```

This article could also give you some hints:

- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/04/09/developing-a-tabs-component-in-angular-2.html

Thierry

Comment: I need the child to call a method in the parent component

Comment: is printValue the name of the method in the parent controller?

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Yes `printValue` is a method in the parent component...

Comment: This is my child component:

<dialogJob [job]="job"  (some-event)="jobCancelledNotification($event)"></dialogJob>

Comment: You should have an `EventEmitter` for your `someEvent` property (decorated with `@Output`. When calling the `emit` method on it `jobCancelledNotification($event)` will be executed. Make sense?

Comment: I've mirrored your code above and understand what your saying, but doesnt seem to hit the parent method and I get the console error.

This is my parent method: 

  jobCancelledNotification = (event) => {
     console.log("job cancelled via output!!!!"); 
  }

Comment: any ideas about the compiler image I added above?

Comment: Here is a plunkr showing how to implement this: http://plnkr.co/edit/KqQMQHjzU5CtScMPY1f5?p=preview.

Comment: For the compiler error, could you give me the code at line 18 ;-) ?

Comment: line 18:   @Output()
  notificationEvent: EventEmitter;

Comment: Perhaps you could try this: `@Output() notificationEvent: EventEmitter<string>;` if you want to emit of string (parameter of the `emit` method)...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Can we somehow move the `(some-event)="printValue($event)"` part into some parent component method instead of template? I mean like an even handler but within component class?

Comment: In fact the `printValue` method should be part of the parent component since it's triggered when the child component triggers an event. The parent component can catch it like this...